# Problem with hline in new tabular environment

Tags: tables, environments

When I write truth tables I like a bit more space in the cells, so I assign new values to `arraystretch` and `tabcolsep`, like this ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{| c  | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    $Q$ & $R$ & $Q \lor R$ \\ \hline \hline
    T & T & T \\
    T & F & T \\
    F & T & T \\
    F & F & F \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

... and all is well.

Eventually I made a new environment for truth tables:

```
\newenvironment{truthtabular}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
    \begin{tabular}{#1}{%
    }
}{\end{tabular}}
```

The environment worked fine unless I wanted the hline at the top, in which case I would get the following errors:

```
Misplaced \noalign. \hline
You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders. \hline
Missing number, treated as zero. \hline
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \hline
```

Attempting to diagnose the problem, I removed the reassignments from the definition of the new environment, thus:

```
\newenvironment{truthtabular}[1]{%
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    %\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
    \begin{tabular}{#1}{%
    }
}{\end{tabular}}
```

The compilations still fails, with the same errors, when beginning with an hline.  Example of failure follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{truthtabular}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}{%
    }
}{\end{tabular}}

\begin{truthtabular}{| c  | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    $Q$ & $R$ & $Q \lor R$ \\ \hline \hline
    T & T & T \\
    T & F & T \\
    F & T & T \\
    F & F & F \\
    \hline
\end{truthtabular}
\end{document}
```

Why does the leading hline cause problems in the defined environment?  What can be done to avert the problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spurious pair of braces in your definition.

I slightly improved your table, using `\\hhline` for the double line, and I propose another layout:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, hhline, booktabs} 
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor} 
\newenvironment{truthtabular}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm} \tabular{#1}
}{\endtabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{truthtabular}{| c | c | c | }
    \hline
    $Q$ & $R$ & $Q \lor R$ \\ %
    \hhline{:=:=:=:}
    T & T & T \\
    T & F & T \\
    F & T & T \\
    F & F & F \\
    \hline
\end{truthtabular}

{ % begin box
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
 \begin{truthtabular}{cc!{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\vrule width1.5pt}c }
 $Q$ & $R$ & $Q \lor R$ \\ %
 \midrule
 T & T & T \\
 T & F & T \\
 F & T & T \\
 F & F & F 
\end{truthtabular}
} % end box

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was it.  (First new environment for me.)  Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! I've added another, nicer in my opinion,  way of displaying the table.

Comment: Excellent!  And helpful in for me in getting started on `hhline` and `booktab`.

Comment: Concerning `booktabs`, note I made an unorthodox use of it: normally it adds some vertical padding around horizontal rules (`\above/belowrulesep`), which I had to annihilate to have crossing vertical and horizontal rules. Normally, you shouldn't use vertical rules with booktabs.

Answer (score 3):

The `\hrule` has to be the first element in the row. In your example, you've placed an empty group at the top of the `truthtable` environment since you finished off your `\begin{truthtable}` definition with an empty group. The following minimal example replicates your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  {} \hline % <---- not good
  table
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Remove this empty group (as well as the [spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)) all peace will be restored:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,eqparbox}

\newenvironment{truthtabular}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764
   %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}% ...if you still need it
   \begin{tabular}{#1}}
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{truthtabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  \eqmakebox[ttt]{$Q$} & \eqmakebox[ttt]{$R$} & \eqmakebox[ttt]{$Q \lor R$} \\
  \midrule
  T & T & T \\
  T & F & T \\
  F & T & T \\
  F & F & F \\
  \bottomrule
\end{truthtabular}

\end{document}
```

I've used [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for presentation and spacing equality via [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox).

Comment: (+1) Nice idea to use `eqparbox`!

Comment: Yes, it looks _very_ nice!